# Build link using expression in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to be able to build a link to a controller action inside of my controller.  I really want to do something like:

```
<%= Html.BuildUrlFromExpression<Controller>(x => x.ActionName(param)) %>
```

...except in the controller.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could play around with the HtmlHelper methods.  That's what the framework uses internally.

```
string myLinkText = HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(
  new RequestContext(this.HttpContext, this.RouteData), 
  RouteTable.Routes,
  "MyLinkText", 
  "RouteName", 
  "ActionName", 
  "ControllerName", 
  this.RouteData.Values,
  new Dictionary<string, object>() {/* attributes here */}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked out mvc features assembly?It contains html helpers which you want